# R: Extract connected graphs

Tags: r, graph

I've a undirected graph composed of ~300 nodes. The graph is composed of multiple connected graphs (example below with a undirected graph composed of 5 connected graph). Using R, how can I extract each connected sub-graph, and their node and edge count. My graph is represented by a two-column data.frame:

```
node1 node2
node1 node3
node2 node5
...
```

With the example below, the expected result would be

```
Subgraph NodeCount EdgeCount
1        2         1
2        4         3
3        2         1
4        2         1
5        2         1
```

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
library(igraph)
set.seed(1)
g <- simplify(graph.compose(graph.ring(10), graph.star(5, mode = "undirected"))) + edge("7", "8")
dg <- decompose.graph(g)
t(sapply(seq_along(dg), function(x) c(Subgraph = x, NodeCount = vcount(dg[[x]]), EdgeCount = ecount(dg[[x]]))))
#      Subgraph NodeCount EdgeCount
# [1,]        1         7        12
# [2,]        2         2         1
# [3,]        3         1         0
```

The example graph looks like this (`plot(g)`):

[image]

Comment: ok thanks. I never use iGraph package, any idea to create a graph using a two-column data.frame ? thanks

Comment: Sure, see `?igraph::graph.data.frame`.